# Gate-induced noise contribution of transistor

Tags: noise

M2 transistor from circuit (a).

[image]

This is the solution:

[image]

Inside the red circle is the gate-induced noise contribution of transistor M2, in my opinion it should be \$4kT\gamma/g_{m2}\$.

The gate-induced noise is a current source connected between the source and drain, so I modelled that current source by a voltage source in series with the gate; the gate is connected to Vout so it should be \$4kT\gamma/g_{m2}\$.

In circuit (e), the M2 gate-induced noise contribution is \$4kT\gamma/g_{m2}\$ (you can see it in the blue circle), so I'm not sure if the author's solution is right or not. In circuits (b) and (d) they did the same thing as in circuit (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output referred voltage for M2 can be computed as

$$\overline{v_{n,out}^2}=\overline{i_{n,d2}^2}\cdot (\frac{1}{g_{m2}})^2$$

This is the current noise source at the output, then converted to a voltage by the diode-connected transistor M2.

Then substituting this noise:

$$\overline{i_{n,d2}^2} = 4kT\cdot g_{m2}\cdot \gamma$$

You would indeed conclude that

$$\overline{v_{n,out}^2}=\frac{4kT\gamma}{g_{m2}}$$

My guess is that they simply didn't multiply by the output impedance (squared).

Also, it is fairly straightforward to see that this is a mistake in the solution. The units of the expressions simply don't match.